# Munkres exercise

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**Problem**

Let $\{A_\alpha\}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$; let $X=\bigcup_{\alpha}A_\alpha$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$;suppose that $f\vert_{A_\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$.

An index family of sets $\{A_\alpha\}$ is defined to be locally finite if each point $x$ has a neighborhood that intersects $A_\alpha$ for only finitely many values of $\alpha$. Show that if the family $\{A_\alpha\}$ is locally finite and each $A_\alpha$ closed, then $f$ is continuous.

**Attempted Solution**

It suffices to show that $f^{-1}\left(V\right)$ is closed in
$X$ for any closed set $V$ in $Y$. Pick an arbitrary $x\in\overline{f^{-1}\left(V\right)}$
, then we have $U\cap f^{-1}\left(V\right)\neq\emptyset$ for any
open set $U$ containing $x$. By local finiteness, $\exists$ an
open neighborhood $N$ such that $x\in N$ and $N\cap A_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$
for finitely $\alpha,$ namely $\left\{ A_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{k}$.
Since $x\in U\cap N,$ we have 
\begin{align}
U\cap f^{-1}\left(V\right)\cap\left(\cup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}\right) & =U\cap\left[\cup_{i=1}^{k}\left(f^{-1}\left(V\right)\cap A_{i}\right)\right]\\
 & =U\cap\left(\cup_{i=1}^{k}f\vert_{A_{i}}^{-1}\left(V\right)\right)\\
 & \supset U\cap N\cap\left(\cup_{i=1}^{k}f\vert_{A_{i}}^{-1}\left(V\right)\right)\neq\emptyset
\end{align}
from which we have that $x\in\overline{\cup_{i=1}^{k}f\vert_{A_{i}}\left(V\right)}$.
Note that $f\vert_{A_{i}}$ is continuous, so $f\vert_{A_{i}}^{-1}\left(V\right)=f^{-1}\left(V\right)\cap A_{i}$
is closed in the subspace topology of $A_{i}.$ So $f\vert_{A_{i}}^{-1}\left(V\right)=F_{i}\cap A_{i}$
for some closed set $F_{i}\subset X$. Since $A_{i}$ is closed, $f\vert_{A_{i}}^{-1}\left(V\right)$
is closed in $X$ as well. Thus, $x\in\cup_{i=1}^{k}f\vert_{A_{i}}^{-1}\left(V\right)=f^{-1}\left(V\right)\cap\left(\cup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}\right)\subset f^{-1}\left(V\right)$,
from which we conclude $\overline{f^{-1}\left(V\right)}\subset f^{-1}\left(V\right)$
and as a result, $f^{-1}\left(V\right)$ is closed because it contains
all the limit points.

**Question**

(1).This is is problem in Munkrs topology. I tried to solve it and I think I had it. I really appreciate is anyone can take a look at my solution.

Comment: @hermes why is it so small to read though. I can see a full size pic here.

Comment: Sorry I mean on cell phone, it looks smaller than other text.

Comment: @hermes corrected!

Comment: For future reference, http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is amazing for finding the $\LaTeX$ command for a given symbol.

Comment: @Math1000 thanks

Comment: $N_x$ suddenly appears in your proof without any definition or explanation of what it is.

Comment: Let's see: the first $\implies$ you have means something like "we have". The second appears to mean "Let $N_x$ be a neighborhood of $x$ such that $N_x$ intersects only finitely many $N_\alpha$, then" The third "Now we know that". The fourth means "Therefore". By some miracle, the fifth actually means "which implies (since $U$ is arbitrary)". I.e., only once in 5 tries did you use the implies arrow correctly.

Comment: I suppose if you interpret #3 as "and", then #4 could also be considered an actual implication. But still, you are misusing the symbols, which in itself makes your proof much harder for others to interpret, regardless of whether symbolism is accepted in a formal proof. Another problem: I believe that saying $f|_{A_i}$ is continuous means with respect to the subspace topology. So you only know that $f|_{A_i}^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $A_i$, not in $X$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree with the part about the symbol. $f\vert_{A_i}(V)$ is closed because $A_i$ is closed by assumption. So we have $f\vert_{A_i}(V)=F\cap A_i$ for some $F$ closed in $X$. Because $A_i$ is closed,$F\cap A_i$ is closed as well.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that assumption. Your logic appears to be correct, then. But you need to do some work to communicate it more clearly. Another correctable issue: You need to state that $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have modified my argument significantly. Could you take a look at it now?

Comment: How you conclude "from which we have that $x\in\overline{\cup_{i=1}^{k}f\vert_{A_{i}}\left(V\right)}$" is not clear.

Comment: Why is $U\cap f^{-1}(V)=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit clearer to build it up:

Lemma: if $A_i, i \in I$ is a locally finite family, then $$\overline{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i} = \bigcup_{i \in I} \overline{A_i}\text{.}$$

Proof: clearly, for any $j \in I$: $A_j \subseteq \cup_{i \in I} A_i$, so $\overline{A_j} \subseteq \overline{\cup_{i \in I} A_i}$. As $j \in I$ is arbitrary, $\cup_{i \in I} \overline{A_i} \subseteq \overline{\cup_{i \in I} A_i}$ as well, which covers one inclusion, which always holds.

If $x \in \overline{\cup_{i \in I} A_i}$, let $V$ be any neighbourhood such that $J = \{ i \in I: A_i \cap V \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite. Suppose (for a contradiction) that $x \notin \overline{A_j}$ for all $j \in J$. Then there are open neighbourhoods $U_j$ of $x$, for each $j \in J$, such that $U_j \cap A_j = \emptyset$. But then $O = V \cap \cap_{j \in J} U_j$ is also an open neighbourhood of $x$ that $O$ misses all $A_i$: those with index outside $J$ because of the $V$, and we also miss all members $A_j, j \in J$ due to the $U_j$. But this contradicts that $x \in \overline{\cup_{i \in I} A_i}$. So for some $j \in J$, $x \in \overline{A_j}$, which shows the other inclusion.

As a corollary: the locally finite union of closed sets is closed (which is more general than the finite case, known from the axioms).

Lemma 2: if $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ and $F \subseteq A$ is closed in $A$, it is also closed in $X$.

Proof: $F = C \cap A$, for some closed subset of $X$ (definition of subspace topology). But then $F$ is a finite intersection of two closed sets of $X$ and so itself closed in $X$.

Proof of the result:

Let $F$ be closed in $Y$. Then

$$f^{-1}[F] = X \cap f^{-1}[F] = (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap f^{-1}[F] = \bigcup_{i \in I} (f^{-1}[F] \cap A_i) = \bigcup_{i \in I} (f|_{A_i})^{-1}[F])$$

The right hand side is a locally finite union of closed sets of $X$ (closed in $X$ because lemma 2 applies and the restricted maps are continuous on their domain). So lemma 1 implies that $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed.

Your proof also tries to prove the lemma 1, essentially (and lemma 2 is mentioned too in passing), but I think it's a bit less clear. The lemmas are also useful in their own right.

Comment: Hi I am sorry for down voting your answer. I hope i can undo it. I misclicked it on my phone app..

Comment: you can click up vote to remove down vote.

Comment: @hermes it says that i voted already and my vote the locked...

Comment: Then you need to edit the post and vote again.

Comment: @hermes I have edited it and waiting for peer review now. Thanks for tip!